# How to rank competitors who all play the same opponent?

Tags: inference, multiple-comparisons

Chuck loves playing pool. He hangs out at a sleezy bar and spends all day playing. Different people drop by to play against him at different times. Everybody who beats Chuck thinks they're the best pool player in town. The problem is that they all work at different times and can't play directly against each other. How can we create a ranking comparing all the players? How sure can we be that the player with the best win record really is the best, the player with the worst record is really the worst, etc.?

Here's an example of my data in R.

```
record <- structure(list(name = c("Billy", "Danny", "Elsie", "Frank", "George", 
"Hector", "Cheryl"), wins = c(26L, 28L, 38L, 43L, 42L, 50L, 49L
), losses = c(46, 42, 46, 43, 42, 37, 34), win_percent = c(0.361111111111111, 
0.4, 0.452380952380952, 0.5, 0.5, 0.574712643678161, 0.590361445783133
)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Think about the limited form of information that's available.  Unless you make (fairly strong) assumptions about consistency of play over time, transitivity, and the relationship between skill and the ability to beat Chuck (which aren't necessarily the same thing!), you can't really estimate any ranking.  When you do make all those simplifying assumptions, all you can do is compare winning percentages. If you want to account for numbers of games played, you're really re-asking the age-old question about how to rank user ratings of products while accounting for the numbers of ratings.

Comment: Thank you for your insight, those are really good points.